# Extract all included files in cpp

Tags: c++, include

I have .cpp file (text).I want to get the list of all files names which are included (#include) to this file.
What is the best way to do it?(Need to implement it in C++)

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: @aschepler - it is cross-platform : could be gcc or vs

Comment: Use any application that supports find and search for `#include`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcc -M source.cpp`

Replace `-M` with `-MM` if you don't care about the system includes.

Comment: I was just looking that up to add as an edit to my suggestion... ;)

Comment: A slightly more sophisticated solution can implement this as its own make target so that you can regenerate the dependencies whenever they change.

Comment: @Code-Guru: This is in fact what I usually do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a "find" or "grep", something along these lines:

`g++ -E source.cpp | grep '\# 1 '`

Comment: "The True Programmer"-style suggestion: use the Clang-LLVM API :-)